# Compress 16 bit raw value in webgl

Tags: opengl, compression, textures, webgl

I have a 3D volume where every voxel is 16 bits. Is there anyway I can use some kind of compression to store the data so I can use less video ram?
Webgl supported different compressiosn if you enable them with extension, but can I use them for a one channel data?

Like `WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc` only supports rgb and rgba data:

```
COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT
```

If its not possible in webgl, is it supported in OpenGL to compress a 16 bit values with one channel?

Comment: Neither WebGL nor OpenGL support *compressing* data, they just support to transfer already compressed data to the GPU which then decompresses it on the fly.

Comment: @LJ_1102: That is not correct. Dunno about webgl, but desktop GL implementations are required to support compressing image data during the texture image specification, as per the spec.

Comment: IIRC the compression algorithms provided by OpenGL are lossy ones, unsuitable for voxel storage.

Comment: @derhass You're right, **its only WebGL** (or more specifically the browsers) not supporting compression because of the licenses and patents on compression algorithms as [Brandon Jones wrote in his blog article](http://blog.tojicode.com/2011/12/compressed-textures-in-webgl.html).

Comment: But if its ok with a little loss, its only support rgba compressed values of floats, not a single channel of 16 bits?